# Is there a way to easily do word suggestions in a CLI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface

I am wondering if there is a package available to help create something similar to what git has built in when you misspell a command, and it suggests existing commands. I am currently writing a CLI, and one of the features of the CLI is dynamically defining commands to dispatch [here is the link for context](https://github.com/Descent098/ahd), so misspellings are quite common.

Ideally I am looking for a way to pass a word, with a list of target words and get suggestions based on how close the input word is to one of the target words.

So for example:

```py
def suggest(input_word:str, valid_words:list) -> str:
  suggestion = "" # The word in list valid_words that input_word is closest to 
  ... # Do stuff
  return suggestion
```

Which can be used like so:

```py
suggest("biild", ["build", "init", "preview"]) # Returns "build"
```

Then with the cli I can use the function to print a message if a command does not exist and is likely misspelled like:

```sh
$ ahd biild
Command "biild" does not exist, did you mean:
    
    ahd build
```

I am not even looking for a full implementation, even just a suggestion on libraries that could help to do the string similarity check would be appreciated. Everything I have found so far is only a CLI with no API to hook into.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) looks promising. I used something similar in the far past.

Comment: For anyone wondering I wrote an in-depth gist based on the responses of @edd and the suggested solution above https://gist.github.com/Descent098/dae85d0235acce5322bf1277d1372a7e